# What should I do if the HR is being less responsive?

Tags: job-offer, human-resources

I received a written job offer and accepted it just a day after. Since the workplace is in another country, it takes some time for registration process and I was asked to send some documents for that.

The thing is, while sending the documents they suddenly became obviously less responsive. Like, I received an email from HR just in few hours each time I sent a document,  but they answered to my last email after 10 days and three follow up inquiry emails.

I would be glad if they just told me they are not considering me for this job anymore but they simply said, "Your application is under process.
We will let you know when we have an update."

I feel like they are buying time maybe hoping another candidate accept their job offer. (I am aware that I was their second option on the list) Am I being paranoid?
This is my first time getting a job like this, is this normal?

Comment: How was the offer presented and accepted exactly? Generally when you accept a job offer then there's no further process to consider, you got it.

Comment: And usually there is a start date.

Comment: Well, I received a written job offer with all details. I send the signed offer to their email.

Comment: There was no start date, I am a doctor I need to get registered in the health system of their country first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep applying, keep interviewing, until you have returned a signed written offer with no conditions.

Because there is still paperwork that is needed before you can start work in the new country, there are conditions. It can take weeks or months to get everything in place. Sometimes these deals even fall through.

So keep the communication going, but keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you, or us, to guess what the delay might be. You can ask them; they may or may not answer. Meanwhile, always continue interviewing until you have a signed and accepted offer with a start date.